# Debian Installer Boots to Kernel instead of Calamares

Tags: debian, system-installation

I've been running into a problem with Debian's calamares installer. More specifically, I can't load it despite having the live iso.

I downloaded the image from [this source](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) -- please correct me if I used the incorrect ones -- and selected the first choice, as selected in the image below. *However*, Debian threw me a command line-like interface instead of the installer similar to that of Ubuntu.

[image]

I am using a Thinkpad running Windows 10. I burned the ISO image to a USB stick using Rufus and booted from it.

This problem has literally stopped me from trying Debian for months. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try selecting "Debian Graphical Installer"?   It's not calamares, but it is graphical. The standard installer is text menus.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify which image you got from your source. I don't run Debian myself, but I am quite sure you have chosen the `standard` image. This one does not include a display server nor a desktop environment. Thus it can't offer you anything else than a terminal. Choose an image that includes a desktop environment like Gnome, KDE, Cinnamon etc. You can see from the image's file name which one is included.

If you do indeed already use an image with a desktop environment and it is not working correctly, please describe in detail what you can see on your screen: Is there some kind of error message? Is the terminal functional? Can you issue commands? If so, try `journalctl -xe` to look for any errors.

Comment: If you look at the [package list of the standard image](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-10.9.0-amd64-standard.packages) you'll notice that there is neither xorg nor wayland included. Live does not necessarily imply graphical imho.